# Align three divs

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am trying to align three divs across my page with one always staying center and the others of equal spacing apart. I have what I think is most of the code I need I just cant seem to get the spacing to work.

```css
#Partnerships div { 
    height: 600px; 
    width: 100%; 
    margin-left: 10px; 
    margin-top: 10px;
    Padding: 10px;
    float: left; 
    background-color: #000000;
    color:#FFFFFF;
   border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
}

#Robe 
   {float:left;
    width:100px;}


#Avolites 
   {float:right;
    width:100px;}


#UKProductions 
   {margin:0 auto;
    width:100px;}
```

```html
<div id="Partnerships div">
<div id="Robe">
    <h1>Robe</h1>
        <p></p> 
            <a href="http://www.robe.cz/" target="_blank">
                <img src="" alt="RobeLogo" height="100" width="200" >
            </a>
</div>

<div id="Avolites">
    <h1>Avolites</h1>
        <p></p>
            <a href="" target="_blank">
                <img src="" alt="AvolitesLogo" height="100" width="200">
            </a>
</div>

<div id="UKProductions">
    <h1>UkProductions</h1>
        <p></p>
            <a href="" target="_blank">
                <img src="" alt="UkProductionsLogo" height="100" width="200">
            </a>
</div>
```

Comment: you can't have this `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` in CSS

Comment: What is the problem, the vertical alignment?

Comment: Horizontally aligned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this example as a guide for your solution:

Flexbox takes care of the alignment horizontally.

```css
#Partnerships {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

#Partnerships div {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Partnerships">
<div id="Robe">
  <h1>Robe</h1>
  <a href="http://www.robe.cz/" target="_blank">
    <img src="" alt="RobeLogo" height="100" width="200" >
  </a>
</div>

<div id="Avolites">
  <h1>Avolites</h1>
  <a href="" target="_blank">
    <img src="" alt="AvolitesLogo" height="100" width="200">
  </a>
</div>

<div id="UKProductions">
  <h1>UkProductions</h1>
  <a href="" target="_blank">
    <img src="" alt="UkProductionsLogo" height="100" width="200">
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'd have to guess it is really not an answer.

Comment: Horizontally aligned

Answer (score 0):

Add this to these code:

```
#Robe, #Avolites {
display: block;
}
 #UKProductions {
display: inline-block;
}
#Partnerships {
text-align: center;
}
```